# Named credentials with POST, url-encoded body and custom grant type for Token generation

Tags: authentication, namedcredentials, accesstoken

Can we use Named credentials against 3rd party with following parameters requirements, which helps us to have access token:

1. **Endpoint**
2. Method - **POST**
3. **URL encoded body** which has following
4. Grant type  = XXX
5. client id
6. client secret
7. scope = XXX

If yes may I know specific ways/link to documentation. 
TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Named Credential delegates its work to Authentication Provider component when oAuth is used as the protocol.  Salesforce ships a number of Auth Providers or you can roll your own. The auth providers available out of the box wrap access APIs for specific platform such as LinkedIn or Facebook. The [OpenID Connect (OIDC) auth provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=5) is the most generic provider available.

Since OIDC is a protocol that is built on top of oAuth, you can provide the usual oAuth primitives as configuration items: client id, client secret, token endpoints, scope(s) and so on. Unfortunately the grant type for OIDC auth provider is fixed - it only supports authorization code grant type (this is undocumented). If you would like to be using other grant types, you need to develop your own auth provider.

Comment: AFAIK, creation of custom class also got some issues. In my case there is no authentication(like no dedicated id/password), it will directly goes for token generation. So how do you suggest I shall go for direct token generation(without any pre-authentication).

Comment: Authorization of access by user via username/password or other means is not part of [Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm) interface. You have to obtain the tokens but how you do it is up to your implementation. See [here](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/JWTAuthProvider) for another example.

Comment: Thank you, will check around that.