# Best Way to Auth Against Microsoft Graph

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, oauth2, third-party

I'm building a LWC/Apex component, that heavily utilises the Microsoft Graph Outlook API. I currently have it set up (still in development) in the way, that for every request I make to the graph API, I also make a `Client Credentials` auth request with hardcoded `client_secret`, `tenant_id` and `client_id`, to retrieve an `access_token`.

To properly implement auth, i've been looking at `Named Credentials`, but it seems that, `Client Credentials` can only be used with `Named Credentials`, when done with a hack: ([Blog Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225121/named-credentials-and-support-for-the-oauth2-client-credentials-grant-type-and-a))

Now I'm a little lost as to what kind of auth I should use, and how should I implement it. Should i use `Client Credentials`, or should i use another type of auth with Salesforce's `Named Credentials` or something entirely else ?

Comment: Best way is subjective and depends on your needs, it's not a Salesforce SE question. Along the lines of Q&A you reference, you have to develop a custom auth provider  if you need whatever token acquisition flow that is not supported by SF out of the box. See these Q&As for more info: [1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268591/using-named-credentials-in-oauth-2-authentication-grant-type-password) [2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291342/named-credentials-with-post-url-encoded-body-and-custom-grant-type-for-token-ge)

Comment: alright - thanks for the response, i'll give it a go